# MongoDB (JS), do query opperations on one document property if available, else take other property

Tags: javascript, database, mongodb, mongoose

So let's say I have following documents in my "Request" collection:

```
{
  pickup: {
    coords: null
  },
  meetup: {
    coords: [ someLng, someLat ]
  }
},
{
  pickup: {
    coords: null
  },
  meetup: {
    coords: [ someLng, someLat ]
  }
},
{
  pickup: {
    coords: [ someLng, someLat ]
  },
  meetup: {
    coords: [ someLng, someLat ]
  }
}
```

The goal is to diplay to the user a sorted list of requests by distance from his position from nearest to farest.

If `pickup.coords` is available it should take that as position reference for follow up expressions, else take `meetup.coords`.

I tried using `$cond` but I get an error and I'm not sure how to use it exactly.

Here is what I thought could work:

```
const query = {
  $cond: {
    if: {
     'pickup.coords': { $exists: true }
    },
    then: {
      // use pickup.coords as reference for distance to user
    },
    else: {
      // use meetup.coords as reference for distance to user
    }
  }
}

const requests = await Request.find( query )
```

Error: `unknown top level operator: $cond`

The request will be much more complicated at the end, because I will do some pagination with `limit` and use `$near` operator with some indexing I think. But it would be nice to get this first step done :-)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: im not sure if you can build the query like that. but you can use in the resulted docs as example `const cords = (pickup.cords || meetup.coords)`

Comment: Shift the logic to the document insert/update. Add a field with coordinates of pickup or meetup, index it and use in geoNear queries.

Comment: @AlexBlex, would it be bad (slow) to `find()` all documents, map through each one, check if field1 is defined, else check condition on filed2 ?

Comment: @MoadEnnagi I don't want do do it like this exactly because of performance issues. I think letting mongo do the filtering itself is the best way to go. Now I just need to know how

Comment: @AlexBlex could you maybe show a pseudo code example please?

Comment: Not sure what pseudocode you expect. I have added an answer if it helps.  The way how to add the field to the model is up to you. Whatever is simpler in your app.  If it is mongoose I guess presave hook would be the best place unless you do raw queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify your application to insert documents in format that supports your queries. Add one more field that contains coordinates you are going to search on:

```
{
    pickup: {
      coords: null
    },
    meetup: {
      coords: [ someLng, someLat ]
    },
    _search: {
      coords: [ someLng, someLat ]  
    }
  },
  {
    pickup: {
      coords: null
    },
    meetup: {
      coords: [ someLng1, someLat1 ]
    },
    _search: {
        coords: [ someLng1, someLat1 ]
    }
  },
  {
    pickup: {
      coords: [ someLng2, someLat2 ]
    },
    meetup: {
      coords: [ someLng3, someLat3 ]
    },
    _search: {
        coords: [ someLng2, someLat2 ]
    }
  }
```

Index on this field:

```
db.collection.createIndex( { _search : "2dsphere" } )
```

Search on this field:

```
db.collection.find(
   {
     _search: {
        $nearSphere: {
           $geometry: {
              type : "Point",
              coordinates : [  someLng4, someLat4 ]
           }
        }
     }
   }
)
```

Comment: Alright thank you, I will go with this for now. The only thing which seems strange to me is, that I have to save the same data twice.